# How to access OWIN based self Hosted WebApi on internet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have developed a OWIN self host webApi application with angularjs 1.6 and c# .net. Am able to access my application on my LOCAL LAN network but unfortunately i lack in knowledge of setting it up a 'self hosted webApi' application over internet and  am struggling it to work on internet. Am looking for some assistance. 
`

```
static void Main()
        {
            bool first = false;
            m = new Mutex(true, Application.ProductName.ToString(), out first);
            if ((first))
            {
                // Specify the URI to use for the local host:
                string baseUri = "http://*:8757";
                Console.WriteLine("Starting web Server...");
                WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUri);
                //MessageBox.Show("Server running at {0} - press Enter to quit. ", baseUri);


                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new MainWindow());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Cannot start another instance of server !!!!!!!" + " ." + " " + "Server is running........");
            }

        }
```

`

Comment: the `baseUri` should contain a public IP address or a dns address that is publicly available. Localhost is not. If you do not know how to get the public address than that is not a coding question and therefore offtopic.

Comment: Dear peter am not talking about coding part, i have done with the coding part, i just need to know to host on internet. Any ways thank you for your suggestion for public ip .. I will try this.

Comment: I tried public ip in the baseUri , but its raising an system.reflection uncaught exception.

Comment: Can you share the full message and stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
G:\AAAA\RWP_Project\QOS_server2\WebOnWin\Program.cs:line 27
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
      .................................This is what the exception am getting.

Comment: did you find out how to do this, please? i need to do that.